# "500 OOPS: prctl PR_SET_SECCOMP failed" - FileZilla Error

Tags: server, connect, filezilla

So I have this Linux Virtual Machine Server at Strato and after they recently did an update I haven't been able to connect via FileZilla but get the Error

*"500 OOPS: prctl PR_SET_SECCOMP failed"*

**I can still:**

-connect via putty

-edit files

-access all pages, login, connect to the database etc

**I can't:**

-connect via FileZilla

**What I tried**

-restarted Server

-reset to a backup

-googled the error message (couldn't find anything understandable)

-contacted strato (after 20min in waiting queue "yeah, your ssh port is open, restart again, we can only check if your ssh port is open" - helpful as ever)

I have no idea what this message means or what I could do to fix it so any explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Juliette

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have presently the same problem. Obviously, they (Strato) have changed something with their virtualization kernels. Update at Strato happened for my V-server on the 21st of Oct.

If you use vsftp then you can circumvent the FTP access problem by setting the parameter 
**seccomp_sandbox=NO**
in your /etc/vsftp.conf.

But this is of course no permanent solution - as it reduces security. 
Just a minute ago I was in contact with Strato. The guys at the helpdesk do not know whats going on. But they promised me an answer by mail.

Ralph

Comment: well glad to know I'm not the only one having the problem -thanks for the tip with the sandbox parameter, I will try it right away - *keeping fingers crossed that strato fixes this*